# How to make a request to the buff163 API?

Tags: java

I make one request to buff163 API:

```
HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpRequest request=HttpRequest
                .newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create("https://buff.163.com/api/market/goods?game=csgo&page_num=1&page_size=2&min_price=150&max_price=200&category=weapon_awp&sort_by=price.asc"))
                .GET()
                .build();

        HttpResponse<String> response = client.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
```

And response is "login required". If i use this request in browser, where I am logged in buff163, response is correct. This API don't have a api-key? How can I make a request from IDE?

I tried to find official documentation to this API, but didn't find anything.

Comment: Simulate a login in code and use the same authentication than from the browser. Or contact the site and ask them.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to aled's comment: for the testing purposes you can use cookies of authorized user. But be careful with requests frequency, do not do it too often to avoid account ban.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to send cookie information with the request. Login to buff163 website and get cookie information from the devtools.

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to use a different link

the following link returns a json with item details to the related item id

https://buff.163.com/api/market/goods/buy_order?game=csgo&goods_id=762135&page_num=1&_=1657808768032

in python some request could look like this:

```
import requests

def buff():
    res= requests.get('https://buff.163.com/api/market/goods/buy_order?game=csgo&goods_id=762135&page_num=1&_=1657808768032').json()
    for price in res['data']['items']:
        url = price['price']
        return url
```

hope its helps